# Page TSconfig and HTMLRTE-Configuration

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, rte

I rework my Page TSconfig and some "problems" have shown yet. My Page TSconfig is published at [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/TmGrUhcu).

1. I want to expand the existing CE menu with additional items. `tt_content_menu.20.x` has been extended. In the selection field, however, no other entry is displayed. (Line 75-84)

Is there something else to do?

2. is in the drop-down lists for block style and text style exclusively No Block Style / No Style Text displayed. There should be additional classes may be selected such as "Important".

Do I need in addition to a matching `RTE.classes`?

Perhaps someone has an idea for this problems?

Comment: Point 1 is cleared, there was a typing error. meue_type instead of menu_type. Now it's works perfect.
Edit at Pastebin.

Comment: Lazy answer: I'm quite happy with my RTE setup, you can look at it at: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/stubr/6o7En

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropdown-Boxes for block-style and text-style will show the additional classes only, if they declared at your personal CSS for the RTE-Backend.